# How do I implement Entity Reference Behaviour Plugins?

Tags: entities, 8, plugins

1. Do [Entity Reference behaviour plugins](https://www.drupal.org/node/1962284) exist for Drupal 8? Please see:
   https://www.drupal.org/node/1803064#comment-10717088
2. Are there any existing examples; documentation or code?

I would like to [upgrade *entityreference_prepopulate*](https://www.drupal.org/node/2615320) but I am unsure about these behaviour plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on IRC via ***berdir***: "no, that doesn't exist". So it simply does not exist yet in D8.

Supplementary info provided for field settings in D8 =>

***berdir***:

> note that fields, like all config entities have a concept of third party settings. you can use that to store per-field settings. didn't check the other parts
>
> see https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats for a projects that uses third party settings on fields